# AXUIElement value attributes

Tags: swift, cocoa, foundation

I want to set exterior app's frame from my own project and I found a problem:

I can set its size and its position (but the thing is, I want it to be full screen, and even if I set the size to be full screen it does not set it's size to it (I have to press the button several times).
I think the problem is with its frame.

```
var frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 23.0, 1280.0, 770.0) //I post only this as size and position seem to work

let sizeCoo: AXValue = AXValueCreate(AXValueType(rawValue: kAXValueCGSizeType)!, &size)!.takeRetainedValue()
let positionCoo: AXValue = AXValueCreate(AXValueType(rawValue: kAXValueCGPointType)!, &position)!.takeRetainedValue()
let frameCoo: AXValue = AXValueCreate(AXValueType(rawValue: kAXValueCGRectType)!, &frame)!.takeRetainedValue()

let errorFrame = AXUIElementSetAttributeValue(myApp, "AXFrame", frameCoo)
```

Setting sizeCoo and positionCoo give me an error with raw value = 0 - everythng is ok, but setting frameCoo displays an error with rawValue = -25205 which means:

```
/*! The attribute is not supported by the AXUIElementRef. */
kAXErrorAttributeUnsupported = -25205
```

and I clearly see when I list attributes for this window there is the "AXFrame" attribute.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: According to the Accessibility Inspecetor, size and position are writable, frame isn't. Fullscreen is writable, did you try setting it?

Comment: I was trying to figure it out for an hour or so, and what? I should've set position first instead of size. Now everything works perfectly!